# How to change keyboard shortcut standard function only in exact workbook in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have simple thing. I have a workbook in which I want to paste only value in cell. So I created a macro:

```
Sub Wklej_w()

On Error GoTo Skip:
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
Skip:
End Sub
```

and assigned to CTRL+V shortcut. And it works- I'm only pasting values for cells. The problem is that this makro works in all opened workbooks. So I tried to add:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> nazwa_arkusza Then Exit Sub
```

and

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Public nazwa_arkusza As Integer

nazwa_arkusza = ActiveWorkbook.Name
End Sub
```

but now in other workbooks it won't paste. Is it possible to archive both functions depending on what workbook is active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there, try:

```
Sub Wklej_w()

    If ActiveWorkbook.Name <> nazwa_arkusza Then
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Else
        Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately nope: error 438 object doesn't support this property or method and debug shows Selection.Paste. But it is close- it pastes values in my workbook, but crashes in other workbooks.

Comment: Thanks, it works now, but I think I will abandon this idea, because now in other workbooks it just paste- I don't have this CTRL options to choose what to paste. It also adds other problems like loosing global variable after workbook change, what after saving file in different name etc. so I don't think it is worth effort to implement.